# How to condense grid item inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use "index" to condense my grid container

```
.grid-container {
     display: grid;
     grid-gap: 0px 0px;
     grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
     background-color: black;
     padding: 10px; 
    }

.grid-item {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

Above is what I have in style, below is what I am trying to do in script:

```
for(var index=0;index<23;index++){  
      $('#grid-container').append('<div class="grid-item"><button ></button></div>');
    }
```

Except instead of using index  I want all of the grid containers to be input boxes...how do I do this?

Comment: you have styles for .grid-container but your script is calling #grid-container. Your script needs to be  $('.grid-container').append. I believe you do not need the for loop either. Jquery will find all the grid containers matching the class and append to them.

Comment: Could you rephrase this? "Except instead of using index I want all of the grid containers to be input boxes"